# How to extract data from a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, json-normalize

I am trying to get the asset/free/locked fields along with the corresponding data to populate into columns.  Currently, I can only get the balances column where these fields fall.

Here is the data format.  I don't need anything before 'balances'.  Thinking if I could remove this part of the string maybe then the columns would be created?  Or if there is a another way to do this?

```
'{'makerCommission': 10, 'takerCommission': 10, 'buyerCommission': 0, 'sellerCommission': 0, 'canTrade': True, 'canWithdraw': True, 'canDeposit': True, 'updateTime': 1595872633345, 'accountType': 'MARGIN', 'balances': [{'asset': 'BTC', 'free': '0.00000000', 'locked': '0.00000000'}, {'asset': 'LTC', 'free': '0.00000000', 'locked': '0.00000000'}, {'asset': 'ETH', 'free': '0.00000000', 'locked': '0.00000000'}...'
```

The code so far to get the balances is:

```
account = client.get_account()

assets = pd.DataFrame(account, columns = ['balances'])
```

Any help appreciated.  Got me stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If `account` is a `string`, it must be converted to a `dict` with [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).
- With `account` as a `dict`, use [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to extract the nested `keys` and `values`

```py
from ast import literal_eval
import pandas as pd

# if account is a string
assets = pd.json_normalize(literal_eval(account), 'balances')

# if account is a dict
assets = pd.json_normalize(account, 'balances')

# display(assets)
  asset        free      locked
0   BTC  0.00000000  0.00000000
1   LTC  0.00000000  0.00000000
2   ETH  0.00000000  0.00000000
```

### Sample Data as a `str`

```py
data = "{'makerCommission': 10, 'takerCommission': 10, 'buyerCommission': 0, 'sellerCommission': 0, 'canTrade': True, 'canWithdraw': True, 'canDeposit': True, 'updateTime': 1595872633345, 'accountType': 'MARGIN', 'balances': [{'asset': 'BTC', 'free': '0.00000000', 'locked': '0.00000000'}, {'asset': 'LTC', 'free': '0.00000000', 'locked': '0.00000000'}, {'asset': 'ETH', 'free': '0.00000000', 'locked': '0.00000000'}]}"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the information, I learned something new.  Solution works great.  Amazed how powerful Python is, and in some ways very easy.  But syntax and can do this with this, but not this.  Wow it's a lot. lol